# Raising the Paint event in NUintTestCases in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit

I am new to Windows forms and NUnit Test cases, I have custom control(DataGrid), I have to check how many times Paint event is raised while creating the control in NUnit test cases. But the Paint event is not raise, could you please suggest how can i raise the the Paint event?

```
    public void Grouping_CheckBottomForIndentCellMethod()
     {
         DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
         dataGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 500);
         dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
         dataGrid.ItemsSource = (new OrderInfoRepositiory()).Orders;
         dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { HeaderText = "OrderID", MappingName = "OrderID" });
         dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { HeaderText = "CustomerID", MappingName = "CustomerID" });
         dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { HeaderText = "CustomerName", MappingName = "CustomerName" });
         dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { HeaderText = "Country", MappingName = "Country" });
         dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { HeaderText = "ShipCity", MappingName = "ShipCity" });

         dataGrid.Paint += dataGrid_Paint;

         dataGrid.Show();


         if (i != 1)
             Assert.Fail("PaintRaisedMultipleTimes");
     }

     void dataGrid_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         i++;
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Farjana Parveen Ayubb

Comment: From your code it's not clear what is your code

Comment: It will not be raised until the control is actually shown.

Comment: TaW - I have a Custom Control DataGrid, but i have call the DataGrid.Show() method please check the code example

Comment: Your grid doesn't belong to a parent.  It needs to be added to someone's control collection.